# Function calls twice in angular 4

Tags: angular

In my Angular 4 project ngOnInit function works perfectly for the first time, but when navigate from another page then ngOnInit is called twice. How do I prevent that?

Comment: please revise the post to add more information. Also consider reading the [**asking help center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question

Comment: Please provide some code for the problem so that the problem could be understood clearly.

Comment: Does it fire the ngOnInit twice or some subscription you fire inside of the ngOninit ? Probably you forgot to unsubscripe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any code, so let me make an assumption : **are you making http calls in your ngOnInit function ?**

If so, you probably wrote `subscribe` : this means **you have subscribed to events, and forgot to unsubscribe**. This means when you come back, you create a second subscription, thus making 2 calls.

Comment: if you want to ask a question: "are you making http calls in your ngOnInit function ?", this belongs in the comments.